# Static local variable colorization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to colorize a function's static variable?

I have tried to customize editor.tokenColorCustomizations. For that i have used "Inspect Editor Token and Scopes" and them field "modifiers".
I have figured out static local variable has only "local" modifiers just like non-static local variable.

I also have tried to use "storage.modifiers.static" scope, but it highlights a static-keyword, not the variable.

Comment: What is this "local" modifier? Did you mean the `thread_local` specifier instead?

Comment: By local *modifier* — did you mean *local scope* or what?

Comment: for that you need an AST an analyze the AST to find the type/modifier of a variable, for that you need to modify the C++ extension and add some semantic colorings

Comment: @RohanBari I have mixed up.  "Modifiers"  is a field of "Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes". So static local variable has "local" in that field.